# Symbol letters not showing in html

Tags: python, html, azure-sql-database, symbols

I have a database in Windows Azure. I have created an online shop in python/django which uses the following:

```
{% for c in chocolates %}
     <th> {{ c.chocolate_name }} </th>
{% endfor %}
```

I am currently working on the German website. When I use, for instance, the letter ö, I write its respective html code in the DB (&ouml ;)  . However, in my html template I get exactly the html code of ö (&ouml ;) and not the symbol I want.

How can I change this?

Here a more concrete example:

Let's say I have the table chocolates composed by chocolate_ID and chocolate_name. Then `chocolates = [(1234, &uuml;), (1313, &ouml; )]`. By the way `&uuml;` equals `ü` and `&ouml;` equals ö.

When I run this piece of code:

```
 <table>
     <tr>
         <th> Chocolate_ID </th>
         <th> Chocolate Name </th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
 {% for c in chocolates %}
         <td> {{c.chocolate_ID }} </td>
         <td> {{ c.chocolate_name }} </td>
  {% endfor %}
    </tr>
 </table>
```

I get the following result in the html site:

```
Chocolate_ID | Chocolate Name
1234         | &uuml;
1313         | &ouml;
```

, but what I want is to get the following result:

```
Chocolate_ID | Chocolate Name
    1234     | ü;
    1313     | ö;
```

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: sure this is python related?

Comment: Show an example of actual HTML code, to begin with.

Comment: do you intentionally store chocolate names as html? For example, if `chocolate_name == "<b>&uuml;</b>"` then do you want to include `<b>` ( `{{ chocolate_name |safe }}` )in your html output or do you want to escape it `&lt;b&gt;` (`{{ chocolate_name }}`)?

Comment: the problem I have is that if write a for instance öüö in my db, when I try to show it in html, I cannot access it.

Answer (score 0):

In your `<head>` tags, do you have:

```
<meta charset="utf-8" />
```

there?

Comment: Yes, I have that one.